# Typescript custom bundling

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, tsc, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm testing out AWS AppSync JS Resolvers and i'm currently building them in TS. To be able to use them I transpile each TS file to a JS file to be able to use them as JS Resolver in AWS AppSync and that works. But i also want to transform each local import to to be included in the output JS file.

getUser.ts

```
import { util, Context } from '@aws-appsync/utils';
import { dynamoDBGetItemRequest } from './utils';

export function request(ctx: Context) {
  if (!ctx.identity || !('sub' in ctx.identity)) {
    return util.unauthorized();
  }

  return dynamoDBGetItemRequest({ id: ctx.identity.sub });
}

export function response(ctx: Context) {
  return ctx.result;
}
```

Currently transpiles into getUser.js

```
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils';
import { dynamoDBGetItemRequest } from './utils';
export function request(ctx) {
    if (!ctx.identity || !('sub' in ctx.identity)) {
        return util.unauthorized();
    }
    return dynamoDBGetItemRequest({ id: ctx.identity.sub });
}
export function response(ctx) {
    return ctx.result;
}
```

The issue here is that I need to bundle the `dynamoDBGetItemRequest` in the js file.

Desired outcome: getUser.js

```
import { util } from '@aws-appsync/utils';
const dynamoDBGetItemRequest = (key) => {
    return {
        operation: 'GetItem',
        key: util.dynamodb.toMapValues(key),
    };
};
export function request(ctx) {
    if (!ctx.identity || !('sub' in ctx.identity)) {
        return util.unauthorized();
    }
    return dynamoDBGetItemRequest({ id: ctx.identity.sub });
}
export function response(ctx) {
    return ctx.result;
}
```

**How can i achieve this bundling using `tsc`?**

Additional notes / Context:

- There will be multiple files like this, one for each resolver.
- They must export one `request` function and one `response` function.
- Using NX
- The js file are to be used in AWS CDK like this `appsync.Code.fromAsset('dist/appsync-resolver/some-folder/getUser.js')),` in a [AppSync Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.AppsyncFunction.html)